# Prestashop, Docker, Reverse Proxy Apache and SSL

Tags: docker, apache, symfony, ssl, prestashop

I'm migrating a Prestashop portal to Docker, at the moment with the same version, I am using an Apache reverse proxy to output it but it gives me an SSL error. Inside the back office it shows me the warning of the URL with the port and in the front office it doesn't let me enter, it cycles and shows an error. The docker container log does not show any errors

Do you know how I can force from HTTP to HTTP? I have already modified the .htaccess, confic.inc, and the Link class, but I can't make it work.

Add this code in the **config.inc**:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) AND $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
{ $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'; }
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=str_replace(':443','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Change the $force_ssl variable inside the **Link.php** file to true:

```
public function getBaseLink($idShop = null, $ssl = null, $relativeProtocol = false)
    {
        static $force_ssl = true;  /*CHANGED*/

        if ($ssl === null) {
            if ($force_ssl === null) {
                $force_ssl = (Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') && Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE'));
            }
            $ssl = $force_ssl;
        }

        if (Configuration::get('PS_MULTISHOP_FEATURE_ACTIVE') && $idShop !== null) {
            $shop = new Shop($idShop);
        } else {
            $shop = Context::getContext()->shop;
        }

        if ($relativeProtocol) {
            $base = '//'.($ssl && $this->ssl_enable ? $shop->domain_ssl : $shop->domain);
        } else {
            $base = (($ssl && $this->ssl_enable) ? 'https://'.$shop->domain_ssl : 'https://'.$shop->domain); /*CHANGED second http to https */
        }

        return $base.$shop->getBaseURI();
    }
```

**.htaccess**

````
 DirectoryIndex index.php
    
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
    
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
        RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    
    
        # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
        # Keep legacy entry points
        RewriteRule ^(ajax|ajax_products_list|ajax-tab|backup|cron_currency_rates)\.php - [P]
        RewriteRule ^(displayImage|drawer|footer\.inc|functions|get-file-admin)\.php - [P]
        RewriteRule ^(grider|header\.inc|init|login|password|pdf|searchcron)\.php - [P]
    
        # If the URL is a legacy on index.php?controller=..., do not rewrite (let the legacy take it)
        RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)controller=|(^|&)tab=
        RewriteRule .* - [P]
    
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule .? - [L]
    
        RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_alias.c>
            RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    </IfModule>
    
    RewriteEngine on
    
    RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
    RewriteRule ^api(?:/(.*))?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^upload/.+$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [QSA,L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
    </IfModule>
    
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType font/ttf .ttf
    AddType font/otf .otf
    AddType application/font-woff .woff
    AddType font/woff2 .woff2
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$">
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </FilesMatch>
    
        <FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
          Header set Content-Disposition "Attachment"
          Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
    
    <Files composer.lock>
        # Apache 2.2
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    
        # Apache 2.4
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
    </Files>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset Etag
    </IfModule>
    FileETag none
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        <IfModule mod_filter.c>
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript font/ttf application/x-font-ttf font/otf application/x-font-otf font/opentype image/svg+xml
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mime_module>
      AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php72___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
    </IfModule>
    ```
    
    ```
    **app.conf
    **
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    
    SSLEngine on
    
    ProxyPass / http://URL:8096/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://URL:8096/
    
    <Location />
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{URL}/$1 [R=301,L]
````